# Vue.js setup() and mounted()

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am fairly new to Vue.js and am currently working on a project. I currently have some constants declared in setup(), lets call one of the constant "c", and I want to get them from within mounted(). I realized that I can still `console.log(this.c)` within mounted() to get the constant printed out but when I try to `console.log(this.c)` within a function in mounted() I can no longer get it and I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`.

Why is this so? And what work arounds are there?

Example:

```
    setup() {
       const c = ref(1)
    },

    mounted() {
       console.log(this.c) // prints 1 on console
       
       function doesSomething() {
          console.log(this.c) // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
          ...
       }
    }
```

Comment: It's impossible for this code to work. this.c won't be available without `c` to be returned from setup. It's unclear what's the purpose of doesSomething. Usually a function is a method in components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 5):

`mounted` is an option in the options api which is different than the composition api using the `setup` hook, you could use `onMounted` hook in setup to replace `mounted` option:

```js
import {onMounted} from 'vue';

setup(){
 let c='some content'

 onMounted(()=>{
    console.log(c)// don't use this keyword
  })

}
```

Comment: @user15558176 It's possible but not a good practice. setup is supposed to fully replace options api, so the latter can be considered legacy.

Answer (score 4):

The function `doSomething` in the mounted hook should be declared with an *[arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)* instead, since *[function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)* has its own `this` binding:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.c)

  const doesSomething = () => {
    console.log(this.c) // Ok
  }
}
```